# Mysql many to many relations. Filter exact match

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

[image: My schema]

Hello. I want to select dishes which has the only the exactly selected ingredient alias?
For example:
Ingredient alias table:

```
+----+----------+
| id |   Name   |
+----+----------+
| 22 |  potato  |
| 23 |  rice    |
| 29 |  chicken |
+----+----------+
```

Ingredient table:

```
+------+-----------+----------+-------+------+----------+
|  id  |   name    | proteins | carbs | fats | alias_id |
+------+-----------+----------+-------+------+----------+
| 3043 | Chicken 1 | 44.0     | 3.0   | 3.0  |       29 |
| 3025 | Rice 1    | 44.0     | 32.0  | 23   |       23 |
| 3024 | Rice 2    | 23.0     | 22.0  | 33.0 |       23 |
| 3042 | Chicken 2 | 22.0     | 22.0  | 3.0  |       29 |
| 3022 | Potato 1  | 22.0     | 22.0  | 32.0 |       22 |
| 3021 | Potato 2  | 20.0     | 30.0  | 40.0 |       22 |
| 3041 | Chicken 3 | 11.0     | 11.0  | 11.0 |       29 |
| 3026 | Rice 3    | 1.0      | 1.0   | 1.0  |       23 |
| 3023 | Potato 3  | 1.0      | 2.0   | 3.0  |       22 |
+------+-----------+----------+-------+------+----------+
```

Table Meal:

```
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| id |                  name                   |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
|  1 | Meal with Chicken 1 and Rice 1          |
|  2 | Meal with Chicken 1 and Rice 2          |
|  3 | Meal with Chicken 2 Potato 1            |
|  4 | Meal with Chicken 2 Potato 1 and Rice 1 |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
```

Table meal_ingredient:

```
+-------+---------+---------------+--------+------+
|  id   | meal_id | ingredient_id | weight | role |
+-------+---------+---------------+--------+------+
| 13366 |       1 |          3043 |     13 |    1 |
| 13367 |       1 |          3025 |      1 |    1 |
| 13368 |       2 |          3043 |     12 |    2 |
| 13369 |       2 |          3024 |      8 |    3 |
| 13370 |       3 |          3042 |     22 |    1 |
| 13371 |       3 |          3022 |      1 |    1 |
| 13372 |       4 |          3042 |      3 |    1 |
| 13373 |       4 |          3022 |      3 |    3 |
| 13374 |       4 |          3024 |      2 |    2 |
+-------+---------+---------------+--------+------+
```

How I can get meals **only** which has ingredients **only** with ingredient aliases Potato and chicken? In my example, the result must be a meal with id 3  Meal with Chicken 2 Potato 1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join all 4 tables, group by meal and put the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
select m.id, m.name
from ingredient_alias ia
inner join ingredient i on i.alias_id = ia.id
inner join meal_ingredient mi on mi.ingredient_id = i.id
inner join meal m on m.id = mi.meal_id
group by m.id, m.name
having 
  count(distinct ia.name) = 2
  and 
  sum(ia.name not in ('potato', 'chicken')) = 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4DyeGSfw7ioWA6fPGzBXB3/1).
Results:

```
| id  | name                             |
| --- | -------------------------------- |
| 3   | Meal with Chicken 2 and Potato 1 |
```

Comment: Hello! Thank for replying. I have tried this query but it doesn't work. If we have another meal which has ingredients from 3 aliases, for example -Meal with Chicken 2 and Potato 1 AND RICE - your query will return this meal also. But I need only **Meal with Chicken 2 and Potato*** without Rice. I updated example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select m.meal_id
from meal_ingredient m join
     ingredient i
     on m.ingredient_id = i.id left join
     ingredient_alias ia
     on ia.id = i.ingredient_alias_id
group by m.meal_id
having count(ia.id) = count(*) and                           -- all ingredients in meal match list
       count(*) = (select count(*) from ingredient_alias)    -- all ingredients in list are present
```

If you can have duplicates, the second condition should be `count(distinct m.ingredient_id)` instead of `count(*)`.

Comment: Thank you for replay. But your Join has the wrong condition. the meal_ingredient table doesn't has the reference  to ingredient_alias. I corrected it with : `inner join ingredient ON m.ingredient_id = ingredient.id
         inner join ingredient_alias ia on ingredient.ingredient_alias_id = ia.id` But it didn`t help.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with ingredient categories that you call ingredient aliases. E.g. you have the category 'rice' which can be 'white rice', 'red rice', and whatever other rice. You are looking for meals that consist exactly of a group of given ingredient categories, e.g. 'rice' and 'chicken'. In the worst case your meal contains a category multiple times. Lets say a meal consists of 'chicken' and 'white rice' and 'red rice'. In spite of having three ingredients, this meal consists of only two ingredient categories.

As of MySQL 8:

```
with ia as
(
  select id from ingredient_alias where name in ('potato', 'chicken')
)
select *
from meal
where id in
(
  select mi.meal_id
  from meal_ingredient mi
  join ingredient i on i.id = mi.ingredient_id
  left join ia on ia.id = i.alias_id
  group by mi.meal_id
  having count(distinct ia.id) = count(distinct i.alias_id)
     and count(distinct ia.id) = (select count(*) from ia)
);
```

For an older version remove the `WITH` clause and write the left join and the subquery without it (or count yourself and replace the subquery with that number).

Answer (score 0):

i have a simple approach:
- join 4 table and select the meal id that ingredient name not in ('potato', 'chicken')
- select the meals that the id not in the set of ids found above.
Here the code (SQL server):

```
select * from test.dbo.meal where test.dbo.meal.id not in (
  select m.id from test.dbo.meal m 
      inner  join test.dbo.meal_ingredient mi on m.id = mi.meal_id
      inner  join test.dbo.Ingredient i on i.id = mi.ingredient_id
      inner  join test.dbo.Ingredient_alias ia on ia.id = i.Ingredient_alias_id
  where ia.name not in ('potato', 'chicken')
)
```

Comment: It is also a possible variant but it is the hight probability that  subquery returns a lot of meals, that's why will be a lot of ids in not in (more than 100) which is really bad for Mysql

Comment: agree. @forpas has the better answer